# Excel VBA accessing Web Page to modify values: run time error access denied 2147024891 (80070005)

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to automate information copy between Excel and Web Page.  Tx to help from you at StackOverflow I finally came up with some code that is working perfectly on my station.
Problem is that it won't work on any other station of my colleagues.  Even more strange I get a run time error , at soon as it the code tries to acces the property of the page.  I tried to run the code line by line to make sure it's not a problem of web page not being completely loaded.
So here's the beginning of the code until it gives:   run time error access denied 2147024891 (80070005)

```
Sub copie_infos_intranet_sur_le_projet()

Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim buttonCollection As Object
Dim valeur_heure As Object
Dim links As Object

lig = ActiveCell.Row
num_proj = Cells(lig, 4)

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "http://intranet.cima.ca/fr/application/paq/projets/index.asp?v1_lang=1"

' Wait while IE loading...
'do while IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Do Events: Loop

'While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'    DoEvents:
'Wend
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents:
Wend

 Set links = IE.Document.frames(2).Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Of course there's more code below but as I said, I get the runtime error at this line?

As I said everything works just fine on my station and I don't have any "security special level privilege"  so it wouldn't be my first guess why it's only working on my station.

So what could be the problem?

Any suggestions/solutions will be greatly appreaciated

Comment: This [article](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm) might be an interesting read. I fear your colleagues do not have the same access of internet automation to the intranet.

Comment: This problem can be a bit of a mystery and I've even had it inexplicably appear then disappear (at least inexplicable in that I could not explain or reproduce it reliably). Take a single machine that it is not working on and open IE then `Alt` , Tools ► Internet Options ► Content ► Clear SSL state. Reporting back with success or failure would be appreciated as I would like to discover the root cause and have a solution ready.

Comment: Make sure your intranet site is added to the Trusted Site zone and lower the security descriptors for that zone.

Comment: @matteo & jeeped . Tx for the suggestion i'll try it tomorrow morning first thing. Will keep you posted!

Comment: @Jeeped no luck with both suggestions.    MatteoNNZ tx for the articles but I can't find any différences between my settings and ones of my colleagues.  Thanks for your help.  Any more suggestions?  Somebody, someone?   Tx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. One day it was working fine, the next day, "access denied"... While on another CPU it was working fine. A bit of a mystery and very anoying!

I have been able to get it to work again: 
 - Clearing SSL state, 
 - Setting privacy settings to Low and 
 - Enable SSL 2.0 (if unchecked) in Advanced Options.

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Will take a shot at your suggestions as soon as I can.  Tx Marcel, will let you know if it works

Comment: Still no luck with this either.  Tx for your suggestion @Marcel.  If I had enough points I would place a Bounty on this...